Issue With RXJS Subject Wrapper
I have a class that contains an RXJS Subject and I'd like to add a shorthand on the class to allow for either piping or subscribing without needing to access the subject directly, but I'm having some issues with making it work.
This is the basic version of my class (the full code is more complex, but this allows for minimal reproduction):
class Wrapper:
  private subject = new Subject<string>();

I've tried two solutions, neither of which have worked. For the sake of the example I'll only reference the pipe, but the same issue also occurs when trying to wrap the subscribe.
The first is with a getter that simply returns a reference to the subject's pipe.
public get pipe() {
  return this.subject.pipe;
}

However, when I do this I get the following error TypeError: Unable to lift unknown Observable type once I add any operators (for example, new Wrapper().pipe(tap(console.log))).
My second attempt included calling the subject's pipe inside the function in order to replicate the original's behavior, like so:
public pipe(...operators: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]) {
  return this.subject.pipe(...operators);
}

When attempting this I get the following compilation error A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. I have managed to find a workaround by casting the operators parameter like so this.subject.pipe(...(operators as [])), but I imagine there's got to be a better way.
If anybody knows of a way to achieve what I'm aiming for it would be greatly appreciated. I'd prefer a solution based on my first method if possible, but if that's impossible then an alternative to the workaround I have in the second method would also be great.
Thanks in advance and have a lovely rest of your week

I cannot reproduce the problem with the given code. Could you give a minimal, but complete example and include the version of rxjs and typescript?

@Silvermind not sure what you tried but I am able to reproduce the error with the latest TypeScript & RxJS. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test-1m8fsq?file=index.ts

@VenfiOranai There is lots of typing you need to implement to get it done, its not worth the effort in my opinion, so just use pipe, let me know if you want to see it.

@JSONDerulo Thank you for that. I might have had a different version, because I had the same code and didn't get that error.

When i give the spread operation, it is considering the spread array as a single argument, it could be a type issue.
pipe(): Observable<T>;
pipe<A>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>): Observable<A>;
pipe<A, B>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>): Observable<B>;
pipe<A, B, C>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>): Observable<C>;
pipe<A, B, C, D>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>): Observable<D>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>): Observable<E>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>): Observable<F>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>): Observable<G>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>): Observable<H>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>, op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>): Observable<I>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>, op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>, ...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]): Observable<unknown>;

Anyway below is the workaround for a wrapper for pipe, it looks really ugly and I frown on it's usage, but it is achievable.
I use tap as a dummy value, just to reach the property ...operations, which is the property you need to pass the operator functions using the spread operator.
Looking at this code, hope you just use a plain pipe and continue development
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, OperatorFunction, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular asdf
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('asdf');

  subjectPipe(...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]) {
    return this.subject.pipe(
      tap(),
      tap(),
      tap(),
      tap(),
      tap(),
      tap(),
      tap(),
      tap(),
      tap(),
      ...operations
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subjectPipe(tap(() => console.log('it works!'))).subscribe(
      console.log
    );
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Why not just cast the subject to an observable?

  private subject = new Subject<string>();
  public subject$ = subject.asObservable();

In this way both pipe and subscribe are available without access to the underlying subject.

Make sure your pipe method is being called with the right this context by using Function.prototype.bind() method:
public get pipe() {
  return this.subject.pipe.bind(this.subject);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

